# Scalability and Thread-Safety of application scoped bean

Tags: jsf, thread-safety, jsf-2.2

in an ApplicationScoped Bean i have:

```
List<DataRow> doRead(String keyword){
    open FileChannel if not already opened
    ...
    MappedByteBuffer map = fileChannel.map(.... some Bytes block[start, blockLength] )
    ...
    map.get(....);
    ...
}

void doUpdate(String newString){
    open FileChannel if not already opened
    ...
    MappedByteBuffer map = fileChannel.map(.... some Bytes block[start, blockLength] )
    ...
    map.put(....);
    ...
}
```

**Questions:**

lets say, 2 users sending requests at the same time:

**1st** user(session 1) calls `sessionBean.abc{applicationScopedBean.doRead(keyword)}`

**2nd** user(session 2) calls`sessionBean.xyz{applicationScopedBean.doUpdate(newString)}`

now lets say that both methods `doRead()` & `doUpdate()` access the **same Bytes Block**, then

1. if the ApplicationScoped Bean handling (different user) Requests one-by-one (as of my knowledge, this is not correct), then i don't have to care about synchronizing the access to that fileChannel right?
2. but if the ApplicationScoped Bean handling users Requests in parallel mode(Multi-Threading), so i have then to synchronize the access to that fileChannel right?

in Case of No 2:

1. i can synchronize the Object (fileChannel), so that only one "Thread" can access it at a time. but this means, it will be blocked even if other Threads are trying to access different byte Blocks in that file! so this is a bad synchronization in my opinion.
2. i can do the synchronization on a part/segment(Bytes Block) of the **fileChannel**, so i can acquire a lock on the given region of this channel's file.

does this thought make sense? or maybe the thread-pool of the Application Server ensures somehow the safety in such cases?

(just a thought) is the @Asynchronous Annotation helpful here? (i use Tomcat 8, but if necessary, i can switch to TomEE or JBoss etc.)

i tagged JSF, because im not sure how the thread pool of the application Server handles users requests (accessing applicationScoped bean from sessionScopedBean).

**NOTE:** the idea behind this approach is that i am trying to implement something like Database based on Java Memory Mapped Files,
i try to do all the logic in the JSF Application it self, rather than communicate to a "stand alone" application via Sockets or others. so i decided to try it first this way, if it fails i will rethink it.

Your help is greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Why not use an embedded database like H2?

Comment: The application scoped bean simpy was not built for your use case. Use an embedded DB like @Kukeltje says.

Comment: thanks @Kukeltje, i would like to implement my own library. why? is a long story.

Comment: thanks @kolossus, i have many options for implementing such embedded Database, so to eliminate bad ideas, i asked this question. Since i am not sure how JSF handling requests simultaneously, so i am trying to understand this thing first. The main point in my question is: does JSF make any synchronization of requests under the hood?

Comment: The source of both mojarra an myfaces is open. Download it for what you use and do a search on the synchronized keyword